python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully when installing grpcio
I want to install an older version of grpcio (1.51.1) with pip but the following error pops up. However, when installing the latest version everything works fine, only the specific version leads to this error. I already installed Cmake. I dont know why this happens and would be thankfull for an explanation.
pip install grpcio==1.51.1

Error:
Collecting grpcio==1.51.1
  Using cached grpcio-1.51.1.tar.gz (22.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio
  Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [185 lines of output]
      C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\setup.py:43: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on: win-amd64
      Found cython-generated files...
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_project_metadata
      creating python_build
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_auth.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_common.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_compression.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_interceptor.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_runtime_protos.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_simple_stubs.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_typing.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_base_call.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_base_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_base_server.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_call.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_interceptor.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_typing.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\_utils.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\aio\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\aio
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\implementations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\interfaces.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_server_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\beta
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\gevent.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\session_cache.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental\aio
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\experimental\aio
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\cardinality.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\style.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\common
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\abandonment.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\callable_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\future.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\logging_pool.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\foundation
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\base.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\face.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython\_credentials
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_credentials\roots.pem -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc\_cython\_credentials
      running build_ext
      Non-fatal exception:Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 231, in compiler_ok_with_extra_std
          cc_test = subprocess.Popen(['cc', '-x', 'c', '-std=c++14', '-'],
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

      Found cython-generated files...
      building 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' extension
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 280, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 263, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 557, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 379, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 289, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 150, in _get_vc_env
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\setup.py", line 535, in <module>
          setuptools.setup(
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_wheel.py", line 384, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 98, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 359, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 283, in build_extensions
          support.diagnose_build_ext_error(self, error, formatted_exception)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\src\python\grpcio\support.py", line 110, in diagnose_build_ext_error
          raise commands.CommandError(
      commands.CommandError:

      We could not diagnose your build failure. If you are unable to proceed, please file an issue at http://www.github.com/grpc/grpc with `[Python install]` in the title; please attach the whole log (including everything that may have appeared above the Python backtrace).

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i_xfex7\grpcio_f2bc4dbc2f124dd3a5b4b59f1907eda0\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 280, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 263, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 557, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 379, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 289, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A200261629\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\camunda_env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 150, in _get_vc_env
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  Running setup.py clean for grpcio
Failed to build grpcio
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (grpcio)


The line distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ is the essential one.

hoefling has pointed out the core of the error message:
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

you are missing the visual cpp build tools, so in essence a compiler.
But you asked specifically why this happens with the older version and not the new one. The reason is that the newest version has whl files (i.e. pre-built binaries) available for windows and python 3.12 (which you have), while the old one does not. This is why it falls back to compiling a version from source  which needs a C compiler.
What can you do:
a) install the build tools as mentioned in the error message and try again
b) since you have conda, simply create an environment with a python version for which pre-built packages are available. Scanning the files section on PyPi, this seems to be the case for python 3.11.
